# Move all contents from a folder to another with shell script

Tags: terminal, automator, bash, script, command-line

Why does this work?

```
mv /Users/diogosaraiva/Music/Youtube/Novas/* /Users/diogosaraiva/Music/Youtube/Tratadas
```

…but the commands below don't work?

```
mv "/Users/diogosaraiva/Music/Youtube/Novas/*" "/Users/diogosaraiva/Music/Youtube/Tratadas"
```

I had to rename the folder "Youtube" from "Youtube - Downloads", just because this don't work:

```
mv "/Users/diogosaraiva/Music/Downloads - Youtube/Novas/*" "/Users/diogosaraiva/Music/Downloads - Youtube/Tratadas"
```

I want integrate this in an [Automator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator_(software)) app. Is there a better way to move all contents from an folder to another with Automator.app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The space character is used by `bash` to separate different parameters to a command so you need to protect/escape it if it occurs in filenames (or other parameters):

```
mv /Users/diogosaraiva/Music/Downloads\ -\ Youtube/Novas/*  /Users/diogosaraiva/Music/Downloads\ -\ Youtube/Tratadas
```

You can also use quotes to protect the space characters from being misinterpreted by the shell but need to move the `*` outside the quotes then to allow wildcard expansion:

```
mv "/Users/diogosaraiva/Music/Downloads - Youtube/Novas/"* "/Users/diogosaraiva/Music/Downloads - Youtube/Tratadas"
```

Comment: I worked as two commands... One line command for this, exists? Thanks

Comment: It is one line actually, but I changed the sample now to make it more obvious.